# Poor performance in multi-threaded C++ program

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a C++ program running on Linux in which a new thread is created to do some computationally expensive work independent of the main thread (The computational work completes by writing the results to files, which end up being very large). However, I'm getting relatively poor performance.

If I implement the program straightforward (without introducing other threads), it completes the task in roughly 2 hours. With the multi-threaded program it takes around 12 hours to do the same task (this was tested with only one thread spawned).

I've tried a couple of things, including [pthread_setaffinity_np](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html) to set the thread to a single CPU (out of the 24 available on the server I'm using), as well as [pthread_setschedparam](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html) to set the scheduling policy (I've only tried SCHED_BATCH). But the effects of these have so far been negligible.

Are there any general causes for this kind of problem?

EDIT: I've added some example code that I'm using, which is hopefully the most relevant parts. The function process_job() is what actually does the computational work, but it would be too much to include here. Basically, it reads in two files of data, and uses these to perform queries on an in-memory graph database, in which the results are written to two large files over a period of hours.

EDIT part 2: Just to clarify, the problem is not that I want to use threads to increase the performance of an algorithm I have. But rather, I want to run many instances of my algorithm simultaneously. Therefore, I expect the algorithm would run at a similar speed when put in a thread as it would if I didn't use multi-threads at all.

EDIT part 3: Thanks for the suggestions all. I'm currently doing some unit tests (seeing which parts are slowing down) as some have suggested. As the program takes a while to load and execute, it is taking time to see any results from the tests and therefore I apologize for late responses. I think the main point I wanted to clarify is possible reasons why threading could cause a program to run slowly. From what I gather from the comments, it simply shouldn't be. I'll post when I can find a reasonable resolution, thanks again.

(FINAL) EDIT part 4: It turns out that the problem was not related to threading after all. Describing it would be too cumbersome at this point (including the use of compiler optimization levels), but the ideas posted here were very useful and appreciated.

```
struct sched_param sched_param = {
    sched_get_priority_min(SCHED_BATCH)
};

int set_thread_to_core(const long tid, const int &core_id) {
   cpu_set_t mask;
   CPU_ZERO(&mask);
   CPU_SET(core_id, &mask);
   return pthread_setaffinity_np(tid, sizeof(mask), &mask);
}

void *worker_thread(void *arg) {
   job_data *temp = (job_data *)arg;  // get the information for the task passed in
   ...
   long tid = pthread_self();
   int set_thread = set_thread_to_core(tid, slot_id);  // assume slot_id is 1 (it is in the test case I run)
   sched_get_priority_min(SCHED_BATCH);
   pthread_setschedparam(tid, SCHED_BATCH, &sched_param);
   int success = process_job(...);  // this is where all the work actually happens
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   ...
   pthread_t temp;
   pthread_create(&temp, NULL, worker_thread, (void *) &jobs[i]);  // jobs is a vector of a class type containing information for the task
   ...
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It’s really difficult to tell without at least knowing the gist of your code. Is the main thread doing anything at the same time? (If not, multithreading is a waste. If it’s *also* doing disk access, that could really hurt performance.)

Comment: I tested with spawning a single thread to do the task. Ok, I will try to refactor my code a bit and post the relevant parts.

Comment: @minitech: Well, not necessarily a waste, if it's in charge of a UI or something... (although I imagine it isn't in the OP's case)

Comment: @minitech The main thread is doing something. It's periodically checking a MySQL  database for new jobs that have been submitted. When it finds a new job, it creates a new thread to process it. So, the main thread is basically an infinite while loop with a sleep.

Comment: @Aaron: So how often does each thread access the disk(s)?

Comment: @minitech The main thread checks the database every two seconds. The process_job(...) function described above does a query on a graph data structure (held in memory) between two nodes, then writes their distance and path to disk. So, the thread is writing to the file after each query, in which there are thousands of queries to perform...so very often.

Comment: But the non-threaded program also wrote to the file in the same manner, and completed the task much faster...which is my dilemma.

Comment: @Aaron: That could be your problem, then. Try keeping a queue of “things to write” in memory, and have only the main thread write when data becomes available.

Comment: @minitech I might could try it, but the file ends up being nearly 2 GB in size. Or perhaps I can append to the file every 1000 lines of entry or so...

Comment: @Aaron: Yep, writing as data becomes available could be the way to go. Don’t wait ’til they’re all done, of course, unless you have memory to match :)

Comment: @minitech Well, I just did a test where I wrote to the file every 500 lines (instead of every line). Since the file contains roughly 29000 lines, that means it only did 58 writes to the disk. However, the speed of completion is basically the same.

Comment: @Aaron: The writes might still have been simultaneous, though?

Comment: @minitech Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Basically, I have a set of 29000 inputs. For each input, I do some calculation and write the result to the file on a new line. Previously, I wrote a line after each result was obtained. I modified it to wait until 500 calculations were done (stored into a vector), and then wrote the values all at once.

Comment: But, as I noted before, the original unthreaded program also wrote the new result as it was obtained and still managed to be rather fast (2 hours processing time, as opposed to 12 hours).

Comment: @Aaron: I’m saying that if any of your threads try to write simultaneously, the whole thing will slow down a lot. The original unthreaded program didn’t have that problem. If you keep a common queue in memory, even with all the locking and unlocking, writing to that will still be faster; then, when the queue is big enough, the main thread can lock it and write it all to disk.

Comment: I think for this to be possible to answer more concretely than my answer below, we need an example of the actual workload that gives this problem.

Comment: Can we see your "process_job" function?  Without seeing that it will be hard to say what the problem might be.

Comment: @minitech Oh I see. Well, the thing is the files created are independent of each other (two output files for every job), in which threads never write to the same files.

Comment: @Aaron: Assuming they’re on the same disk, that’s still concurrent disk writes.

Comment: @minitech Yes, that's true. Although, for the test I did I only dispatched one thread to do the task (only one write was being done) and it took 12 hours.

Comment: @Aaron: And that’s not nearly enough threads to evaluate the benefits of multithreading this on a 24-CPU server. Really, try the queue ;)

Comment: @Aaron: I'm pretty certain that running one thread as a thread vs. running the code in the main process will have absolutely no effect whatsoever on the execution speed of your code. Threads in themselves do not affect matters much at all, as long as the thread is running freely. I have examples that give exactly 4x speedup running in four threads vs. running in one thread. Every time. Something you are doing is causing a slow-down. Without seeing your code, it's almost impossible to say WHAT that is.

Comment: have you tried timing different parts of the thread's code path? *Something* is slower, but you don't know what. Try eliminating different parts of the algorithm. For example, instead of writing the output to disk, just throw it away (in both the single-and multithreaded versions).

Comment: As @MatsPetersson says, something is wrong in your code, but there is *no* way for us to determine *what* it is. What have you tried in order to debug it?

Comment: You compile with `gcc -pthread`, correct?  When you test the code in `main()` (non-threaded), you also use `gcc -pthread`?  I understand the tests are taking a long time.  However, it could be an issue with libraries and/or compiler.  This helps to diagnose where the fault maybe in the slow down.  Is this a recent Linux?  Are the compiler and Linux both from a distro or did you make one yourself?

Comment: In addition to Bill's latest questions, what CPU do you have?  How many physical cores?  Do you have hyperthreading enabled?  What's the overall system load?  Are you simultaneously writing to the same disk from the main thread and the new thread?  Try running the program with I/O from the main thread disabled.  Why type of disk is it (internal vs. external over USB vs. network, etc.)?  What does a thread-aware profiler (not gprof) say the thread is spending its time doing?

Comment: @Aaron: could you expand on your final edit a little please ? I'm having a similar problem with pthreads and performance and have tried all the obvious things covered here and elsewhere. It seems it might be specific to running a dual core Haswell system (NUMA) (works fine on an older 2 CPU pre-Haswell non-NUMA system). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PaulR Honestly I don't recall all the contributing factors when I had this issue. But, I do recall that the single-threaded program I was comparing against had a more efficient compiler optimization flag which certainly effected the result a bit (I forget exactly, but perhaps it was -O3 or something -- see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

Comment: @Aaron: thanks for getting back to me - I've made some progress on this recently and it looks like I may be able to resolve it by using a thread pool rather than `pthread_create`/`pthread_join`, since this is where a lot of the overhead seems to be coming from on Linux.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you have plenty of CPU cores, and have plenty of work to do, it should not take longer to run in multithreaded than single threaded mode - the actual CPU time may be a fraction longer, but the "wall-clock time" should be shorter. I'm pretty sure that your code has some sort of bottleneck where one thread is blocking the other.

This is because of one or more of these things - I'll list them first, then go into detail below:

1. Some lock in a thread is blocking the second thread from running.
2. Sharing of data between threads (either true or "false" sharing)
3. Cache thrashing.
4. Competition for some external resource causing thrashing and/or blocking.
5. Badly designed code in general...

### Some lock in a thread is blocking the second thread from running.

If there is a thread that takes a lock, and another thread wants to use the resource that is locked by this thread, it will have to wait. This obviously means the thread isn't doing anything useful. Locks should be kept to a minimum by only taking the lock for a short period. Using some code to identify if locks are holding your code, such as:

```
while (!tryLock(some_some_lock))
{
    tried_locking_failed[lock_id][thread_id]++;
}
total_locks[some_lock]++;
```

Printing some stats of the locks would help to identify where the locking is contentious - or you can try the old trick of "Press break in the debugger and see where you are" - if a thread is constantly waiting for some lock, then that's what's preventing progress...

### Sharing of data between threads (either true or "false" sharing)

If two threads use [and update the value of it frequently] the same variable, then the two threads will have to swap "I've updated this" messages, and the CPU's have to fetch the data from the other CPU before it can continue with it's use of the variable. Since "data" is shared on a "per cache-line" level, and a cache-line is typically 32-bytes, something like:

```
int var[NUM_THREADS]; 
...
var[thread_id]++;
```

would classify as something called "false sharing" - the ACTUAL data updated is unique per CPU, but since the data is within the same 32-byte region, the cores will still have updated the same are of memory.

### Cache thrashing.

If two threads do a lot of memory reading and writing, the cache of the CPU may be constantly throwing away good data to fill it with data for the other thread. There are some techniques available to ensure that two threads don't run in "lockstep" on which part of cache the CPU uses. If the data is 2^n (power of two) and fairly large (a multiple of the cache-size), it's a good idea to "add an offset" for each thread - for example 1KB or 2KB. That way, when the second thread reads the same distance into the data region, it will not overwrite exactly the same area of cache that the first thread is currently using.

### Competition for some external resource causing thrashing and/or blocking.

If two threads are reading or writing from/to the hard-disk, network card, or some other shared resource, this can lead to one thread blocking another thread, which in turn means lower performance. It is also possible that the code detects different threads and does some extra flushing to ensure that data is written in the correct order or similar, before starting work with the other thread.

It is also possible that there are locks internally in the code that deals with the resource (user-mode library or kernel mode drivers) that block when more than one thread is using the same resource.

### Generally bad design

This is a "catchall" for "lots of other things that can be wrong". If the result from one calculation in one thread is needed to progress the other, obviously, not a lot of work can be done in that thread.

Too small a work-unit, so all the time is spent starting and stopping the thread, and not enough work is being done. Say for example that you dole out small numbers to be "calculate if this is a prime" to each thread, one number at a time, it will probably take a lot longer to give the number to the thread than the calculation of "is this actually a prime-number" - the solution is to give a set of numbers (perhaps 10, 20, 32, 64 or such) to each thread, and then report back the result for the whole lot in one go.

There are plenty of other "bad design". Without understanding your code it's quite hard to say for sure.

It is entirely possible that your problem is none of the ones I've mentioned here, but most likely it is one of these. Hopefully this asnwer is helpful to identify the cause.

Comment: Note that cache lines are now generally 64 bytes, not 32.

Answer (score 6):

Read [CPU Caches and Why You Care](http://www.aristeia.com/TalkNotes/ACCU2011_CPUCaches.pdf) to understand why a naive port of an algorithm from one thread to multiple threads will more often than not result in greatly reduced performance and negative scalability. Algorithms that are *specififcally* designed for parallelism take care of overactive interlocked operations, false sharing and other causes of cache pollution.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few things you might wanna look into.

1°) Do you enter any critical section (locks, semaphores, etc.) between your worker thread and your main thread? (this should be the case if your queries modify the graph). If so, that could be one of the sources of the multithreading overhead : threads competing for a lock usually degrades performances.

2°) You're using a 24 cores machines, which I assume would be NUMA (Non-Uniform Memory Access). Since you set the threads affinities during your tests, you should pay close attention to the memory topology of your hardware. Looking at the files in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/ can help you with that (beware that cpu0 and cpu1 aren't necessarily close together, and thus does not necessarily share memory). Threads heavily using memory should use local memory (allocated in the same NUMA node as the core they're executing on).

3°) You are heavily using disk I/O. Which kind of I/O is that? if every thread perform every time some synchronous I/O, you might wanna consider asynchronous system calls, so that the OS stays in charge of scheduling those requests to the disk.

4°) Some caches issues have already been mentionned in other answers. From experience, false sharing can hurt performances as much as you're observing. My last recommendation (which should have been my first) is to use a profiler tool, such as Linux Perf, or OProfile. With such performance degradation you're experiencing, the cause will certainly appear quite clearly.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have all addressed the general guidelines that can cause your symptoms. I will give my own, hopefully not excessively redundant version. Then I will talk a bit about how you can get to the bottom of the problem with everything discussed in mind.

In general, there's a few reasons you'd expect multiple threads to perform better:

- A piece of work is dependent on some resources (disk, memory, cache, etc.) while other pieces can proceed independently of these resources or said workload.
- You have multiple CPU cores that can process your workload in parallel.

The main reasons, enumerated above, you'd expect multiple threads to perform less well are all based on resource contention:

- Disk contention: already explained in detail and can be a possible issue, especially if you are writing small buffers at a time instead of batching
- CPU time contention if the threads are scheduled onto the same core: probably not your issue if you're setting affinity. However, you should still double check
- Cache thrashing: similarly probably not your problem if you have affinity, though this can be very expensive if it is your problem.
- Shared memory: again talked about in detail and doesn't seem to be your issue, but it wouldn't hurt to audit the code to check it out.
- NUMA: again talked about. If your worker thread is pinned to a different core, you will want to check whether the work it needs to access is local to the main core.

Ok so far not much new. It can be any or none of the above. The question is, for your case, how can you detect where the extra time is coming from. There's a few strategies:

- Audit the code and look for obvious areas. Don't spend too much time doing this as it's generally unfruitful if you wrote the program to begin with.
- Refactor the single threaded code and the multi-threaded code to isolate one process() function, then profile at key checkpoints to try to account for the difference. Then narrow it down.
- Refactor the resource access into batches, then profile each batch on both the control and the experiment to account for the difference. Not only will this tell you which areas (disk access vs memory access vs spending time in some tight loop) you need to focus your efforts on, doing this refactor might even improve your running time overall. Example:

  - First copy the graph structure to thread-local memory (perform a straight-up copy in the single-threaded case)
  - Then perform the query
  - Then setup an asynchronous write to disk
- Try to find a minimally reproducible workload with the same symptoms. This means changing your algorithm to do a subset of what it already does.
- Make sure there's no other noise in the system that could've caused the difference (if some other user is running a similar system on the work core).

My own intuition for your case:

- Your graph structure is not NUMA friendly for your worker core.
- The kernel can actually scheduled your worker thread off the affinity core. This can happen if you don't have isolcpu on for the core you're pinning to.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you what's wrong with your program because you haven't shared enough of it to do a detailed analysis.

What I can tell you is if this was my problem the first thing I would try is to run two profiler sessions on my application, one on the single threaded version and another on the dual thread configuration. The profiler report should give you a pretty good idea of where the extra time is going. Note that you may not need to profile the entire application run, depending on the problem the time difference may become obvious after you profile for a few seconds or minutes.

As far as profiler choices for Linux you may want to consider [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/) or as a second choice [gprof](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html).

If you find you need help interpreting the profiler output feel free to add that to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a right pain in the rear to track down why threads aren't working as planned. One can do so analytically, or one can use tool to show what's going on. I've had very good mileage out of ftrace, Linux's clone of Solaris's dtrace (which in turn is based on what VxWorks, Greenhill's Integrity OS and Mercury Computer Systems Inc have been doing for a looong time.)

In particular I found this page very useful: http://www.omappedia.com/wiki/Installing_and_Using_Ftrace, particularly [this](http://www.omappedia.com/wiki/Installing_and_Using_Ftrace#Sched_switch_Tracer) and [this](http://www.omappedia.com/wiki/Installing_and_Using_Ftrace#Sched_switch_viewer) section. Don't worry about it being an OMAP orientated website; I've used it on X86 Linuxes just fine (though you may have to build a kernel to include it). Also remember that the GTKWave viewer is primarily intended for looking at log traces from VHDL developments, which is why it looks 'odd'. It's just that someone realised that it would be a usable viewer for sched_switch data too, and that saved them writing one.

Using the sched_switch tracer you can see when (but not necessarily why) your threads are running, and that might be enough to give you a clue. The 'why' can be revealed by careful examination of some of the other tracers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting slowdown from using 1 thread, it is likely due to overhead from using thread safe library functions, or from thread setup. Creating a thread for each job will cause significant overhead, but probably not as much as you refer to.
In other words, it is probably some overhead from some thread safe library function.

The best thing to do, is to profile your code to find out where time is spent. If it is in a library call, try to find a replacement library or implement it yourself. If the bottleneck is thread creation/destruction try reusing threads, for instance using OpenMP tasks or std::async in C++11.

Some libraries are really nasty wrt thread safe overhead. For instance, many rand() implementations use a global lock, rather than using thread local prgn's. Such locking overhead is much larger than generating a number, and is hard to track without a profiler.

The slowdown could also stem from small changes you have made, for instance declaring variables volatile, which generally should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're running on a machine with one single-core processor.  This problem is not parallelizable on that kind of system.  Your code is constantly using the processor, which has a fixed number of cycles to offer to it.  It actually runs more slowly because the additional thread adds expensive context switching to the problem.

The only kinds of problems that parallelize well on a single-processor machine are those that allow one path of execution to run while another is blocked waiting for I/O, and situations (such as keeping a responsive GUI) where allowing one thread to get some processor time is more important than executing your code as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to run many independent instances of your algorithm can you just submit multiple jobs (with different parameters, can be handled by a single script) to your cluster? That would eliminate the need to profile and debug your multithreaded program. I don't have much experience with multithreaded programming but if you use MPI or OpenMP then you'd have to write less code for the book keeping too. For example, if some common initialization routine is needed and the processes can run independently thereafter you can just do that by initializing in one thread and doing a broadcast. No need for maintaining locks and such.