# Low performance when recording command buffers with multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool, vulkan

So basically I've spent the past two weeks trying to figure out why my multithreaded command buffer recording has been so slow, and I'm completely stumped. The problem is, when I try to offload work to multiple threads to record my command buffers, I end up with lower performance than I would have if I had used a single thread. I am very sure that this is an issue with how I have set up my threads/jobs

What I'm doing at the moment is when I begin preparing for the next frame, I tell X amount of threads to record X amount of draw commands in a secondary command buffer (one cmd buffer per thread) All of the work is spread evenly between the X amount of threads that I'm using, however, after keeping track of the times that it takes for each thread to do it work, I noticed that the threads did not finish their jobs any faster when I included more worker threads to do a portion of the work. For example, telling 2 threads to record 100 draw commands each would finish their work in about 5ms, but if I tell 4 threads to record 50 draw commands each they would still finish their work in the same amount of time as it took the 2 threads despite having more threads doing less work in each thread.

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here

My job function looks like this

```
void doRender(CommandBuffer* writeBuffer, VkCommandBufferInheritanceInfo inheritance, Pipeline* pipelineIn, MeshBuffer* meshBufferIn, dragonsbreath4::World* worldIn, int start, int end) {

            writeBuffer->begin(VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_RENDER_PASS_CONTINUE_BIT, &inheritance);

            writeBuffer->bindPipeline(pipelineIn);

            writeBuffer->bindMeshBuffer(meshBufferIn);

            writeBuffer->draw(worldIn->getEntityList(), start, end);

            writeBuffer->finish();

        }
```

The writebuffer is a pointer to the secondary command buffer that will be recorded.
The pipeline is a pointer to the graphics pipeline used by the application.
The meshbuffer is a pointer to an object containing buffers with all of the vertex data and index data.
The world is a pointer to the world that will be drawn.
The start/end is just where on the entity list to begin drawing from and where to end.

I'm pretty sure the issue lies with the fact that most of these resources are accessed by every thread that is recording commands (pipeline, world, meshbuffer)

I hope this is enough information if not I can include more. Any help here would be appreciated!!!

Comment: *I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here* -- The first thing is failing to specify how you built your application in terms of optimization switches.  Are you running a release, optimized build, or a "debug", unoptimized build?

Comment: Note: Starting a thread itself is somewhat costly. And accessing resources which are protected with mutexes would be another reason why the multithreaded approach wouldn't bring a lot of performance. This might be a good read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15178083/11228029

Comment: @ShadowDev  How many CPU cores are on your computer? This is obvious, but still worth mentioning that if the number of working threads is higher than the number of cores, adding more threads will not speed up. Simple measure to start with: what is the CPU load of your process? If it is around 100% with a highly multi-threaded program (while 400% would be expected with 4 threads), that would tend to indicate that all threads but one are blocked on a single shared mutex.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have been running my application on "release x64"

Comment: Do you have validation layers enabled? If so, they might be introducing a lot of contention.